# Select all cells in nth column with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

How do I select all cells in nth column of a normal html table. Ive tried this but its not working:

```
    $('table#foo tbody td:nth-child(3)').each(function (index) {
        $(this).addClass('hover');
    });
```

UPDATE:
Heres a jsfiddle of the unworking code: http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/D5KMq/

Comment: Have you got an example of the markup, in http://jsfiddle.net for example?

Comment: works for me ... http://jsfiddle.net/cefb7/

Comment: me too: http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/XWyAn/

Comment: Heres a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/D5KMq/

Comment: Sorry forgot to include jquery, heres a update that seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/D5KMq/2/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no need to use `each` for this.

```
$('table#foo tbody td:nth-child(3)').addClass('hover');
```

Other than that, there's nothing wrong with your code. Problem must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 6):

Your actual problem (not evident in the original question, but there in the fiddle) is that `.index()` returns a zero-based value, but `:nth-child()` requires a *one-based* value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table#foo tbody td:nth-child(3)').addClass('hover');
```

Use this script (draw your attention that with :nth-child selector index of each child to match, starting with 1)

```
$(".legendvalue", ".stmatst_legends").hover(function() {
    var index = $('.legendvalue').index($(this));

    $('table#stmstat tbody td:nth-child(' + (index + 1) + ')').addClass('hover');


}, function() {
    //remove hover
});
```